# How to download these lecture videos?

Tags: firefox, download, video-streaming

I want to download [these](http://vod.mathnet.or.kr/sub1.php?key_year=2012&key_name=Miles) lecture videos by Miles Reid. I have tried using DownThemAll! firefox extension, but it only saves a .asx file. When I tried to open the .asx file using gedit to get the link, I got this link for first video :
mms://kentro.kaist.ac.kr/200907/Miles Reid5.wmv
If I copy and paste the above address in firefox with mms replaced by http, then the video streams online, but I cannot download it. Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this: http://sdp.ppona.com/

Answer (score 3):

## Using VLC

> [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is a free and open source cross-platform multimedia player and framework that plays most multimedia files as well as DVD, Audio CD, VCD, and various streaming protocols.
>
> <sub>Source: [VideoLAN - Official page for VLC media player, the Open Source video framework!](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)</sub>

1. Open the **Media > Convert / Save** menu.
2. Select the **Network** tab, and enter the stream url (e.g. `mms://kentro.kaist.ac.kr/200907/Miles Reid5.wmv`).
3. Click the **Convert / Save** button.
4. Select the **Dump raw input** option.
5. Choose a name for the destination file, and click **Start**.